# Use a different server on a page Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I am trying to implement a chat to a view on my Angular / NodeJS website.

The `website` is deployed on a server running on port 4200, the `backend` runs on 8000 and for now the `chat` socket.io template runs on 3000.

I have followed the socket.io's official chat tutorial in detail so I have a functionnal chat page that works on port 3000 but how can I implement it to an Angular component?

Here is my code so far:

`server.js`:

```
const app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var http2 = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http2);

http.listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8000');
});
http2.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

const home = require('./home.js');
const chat = require('./chat.js');

// SOCKET.IO for testing purpose, following the tutorial
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket.html');  
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  ...
});
```

`chat.component.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<body>

...

<div class="bottom">
  <form action="">
    <input id="m" class="messageInput" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">SEND</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out to make the chat 'module' work on my HTML page without accessing it through a route (`app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socket.html') });`

What can I do? Thanks! And sorry for being a noob :p

Comment: Any idea anyone? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io is different for client side, It's called socket.io-client. You need to get it using:

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

Well, Martin you don't need to explicitly link script file in the html. You just need to import socket.io-client variable in its typescript file.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'. //And then connect using
try {
        this._socket = io.connect(socket.io_port_you_are_using_in_server.js)
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('error')
    }
```

Now you can use  this._socket wherever required like you are doing in server.js.
I also created an app like you using MEAN stack 7 months ago, but I preferred using service as I have to use chat feature in more than 3 components. I'm giving you some sample code which might help you.

```
 joinRoom(room: string, handler: string): Observable<any> {

        this._socket.emit('join', { 'room': room, 'handler': handler });
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(this._socket.id)
    },10)
    let observable = new Observable((observer) => {
        this._socket.on('new user', (data) => {
            observer.next(data);
        })
    })
    return observable;
}
leaveRoom(room: string) {
    this._socket.emit('leave', room);
    this._socket.removeAllListeners()
}
 getMessages(): Observable<any> {
    let observable = new Observable((observer) => {
        this._socket.on('get message', (data) => {
            observer.next(data);
        })
    })
    return observable;
}
```

Just subscribe to the service and use binding to display msgs on the template.

```
//create array of received msgs
received: any[] = [];
//And in ngOnInit lifecycle hook:
    this._chatService.getMessages().subscribe((data) => {
          this.received.push(data.msg )
```

Now you can use *ngFor in the template to display msgs.

```
<p *ngFor="let msg of received">msg</p>
```

You can customize code as per your requirement.

Good luck dude!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly what I was missing!

Comment: And for the additional information that's going to be really helpful!

Comment: Good to hear that dude. I added more code to help you display msgs on the template, hope it helps you more in project.